# Execute a function for all requests in ZF2 AbstractRestfulController

Tags: zend-framework2

Using ZendFramework `AbstractRestfulController` how can I have a function to be executed for all the request and return the result immediately (if necessary) without explicitly calling it each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following function in your conrtoller where AbstractRestfulController is extended.

```
 public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    $controller = $this;
    $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');

    $events->attach('dispatch', function ($e) use ($controller) {
        $route = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
        $variables = $viewModel->getVariables();
        $currentController = $route->getParam('controller');

    }, 100); // execute before executing action logic
}
```

This will execute every request in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `onDispatch` method.

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
```